# Google FCM: badge counter restricted to iOS?

Tags: php, android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm pretty confused about Google FCM.
The documentation page https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref lists the parameters supported by API, but oddly, the "badge" parameter appears as "iOS" only.

I was setting my android app badge counter successfully until last week, but today, sending parameter "badge" inside the "notification" section does not work. The notification arrives successfully.

My notification data structure:

```
Array
(
    [to] => (device token)
    [notification] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title
            [text] => Test message
            [sound] => default
            [vibrate] => 1
            [badge] => 2
        )
)
```

My server side code (PHP):

```
$jsonData = json_encode($data);

$ch     = curl_init("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
$header = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    "Authorization: key=".MY_GCM_API_KEY
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't support the badge on applications icons to represent non-read notifications.
*(some device manufactures added this feature to be more familiar with iOS, but it's a custom feature on that device. There is not a standard Android API)*

When you send a FCM message, the `badge` parameter is correctly used in iOS but, due to the above explanation,  it's **simply ignored on Android.**

PS: this has been the behavior since the API was introduced in GCM / FCM.

Comment: Hmm...is this answer still valid nowadays?

Comment: yes. In O android introduced badges, but they are handled automatically by the system and cannot be controlled.